# How is the worst time case for this code O(R*C)?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I came across this question on InterviewBit:

```
int memo[101][101];
int findMinPath(vector<vector<int> > V, int r, int c) {
  int R = V.size();
  int C = V[0].size();
  if (r >= R || c >= C) return 100000000; // Infinity
  if (r == R - 1 && c == C - 1) return 0;
  if (memo[r][c] != -1) return memo[r][c];
  memo[r][c] =  V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c + 1));
  return memo[r][c];
}

Callsite : 
memset(memo, -1, sizeof(memo));
findMinPath(V, 0, 0);
```

*Assume `R = V.size()` and `C = V[0].size()` and `V` has positive elements*

Wouldn’t the code create a binary tree sort of function call that takes O(2<sup>(m+n)</sup>), since every function call makes two other functions calls?

Comment: Yes, but for every r+1 you also get a c and a c+1.

Comment: Not an answer, but watch out for that memset! It might seem fine, but if you try to initialize `memo` to just about anything but 0s or -1s that way, things will go horribly wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: And even `-1` won't work on one's complement systems, assuming you ever run into one (I never have; doubt I ever will, but it's good to stick to standards defined behaviors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm makes use of a technique known as [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The essence of this is to memorize intermediate results in a lookup-table and find the overall solution as a combination of partial solutions.

In this particular case, you can see that each call of `findMinPath` will either be a leaf call (not recurse) with constant complexity or else make at least one entry in `memo` become non-negative. It is easy to see that if all entries in `memo` are non-negative, the function will never recurse. Since there are only *R* × *C* elements in `memo`, this is an upper bound to the overall complexity.

That said, the implementation is rather clumsy. Why use a global variable for the `memo` and rely on it being initialized to `-1` by the caller? Also, using `memset` to write an array of integers only works for some integers with all bytes identical, which makes non-portable assumptions on integer layout. And finally, there is a buffer overrun vulnerability if either *R* or *C* exceed the magic value 101. Therefore, if you want to be pedantic, the actual complexity is constant.

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit more clearly in an elaborated way. actually this is a question in interviewbit. there are two questions of similar type. I didn't understand any of them. Can you explain the difference between [this](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/rec_cmpl2/) and [this](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/rec_cmpl3/)?

Comment: @Krishna That's a little much for explaining in a comment. You might consider asking a new question, but please make sure it is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That said, I'm quite busy at the moment and probably won't be able to answer. Somebody else might.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a given (r, c)

the following code will not be executed more than once :

**memo[r][c] =  V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c + 1));**

Once memo[r][c] is set, the functions will return at

**if (memo[r][c] != -1) return memo[r][c];**

So, every function ends up calling other functions at most 1 time. 
In other words, every function ends up executing atmost O(1) times (Note that you can shift the part about checking for memo[r][c] != -1 at the callsite ).

O(R * C) possible number of combinations are possible for (r, c)
Hence, the time complexity of the function : O(R*C)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case time complexity of this code is `O(R*C)`, as we are using the top-down approach of Dynamic Programming by storing the value in memo[r][c], so recursive call will take place only one time and the second time it will execute the following line

`if(memo[r][c] != -1) return memo[r][c]` which has O(1) complexity.

Total combinations possible are `R*C` so it's time complexity will `O(R*C)`